# Finding corrupted videos with python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, stderr, mpeg

I have huge video dataset (about 500000 16 frame length clips). Some of the videos produce messages like

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x561b46a44b80] marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x561b480c0740] Error at MB: 4718
[mpeg4 @ 0x561b4811b640] header damaged
```

I want to find which videos cause the problem.
First I tried with this https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4 solution, but I got nothing in the error files.

My second idea was to read the first image of a video and if it throws an error, save the filename to a file. However, it seems this is not an error message: although the messages appeared on console, `read` returned with `success=True`.

Then I tried to print the filenames to standard error (where the warning messages also go), saving it to a file and do some postprocessing to extract the videos which has problem.

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import sys

folder = '/path/to/videos'
for f in tqdm(os.listdir(folder)):
  sys.stderr.write('BEFORE VIDCAP ' + f + '\n')
  vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(folder,f))
  sys.stderr.write('BETWEEN VIDCAP AND SUCCESS' + f + '\n')

  success, image = vidcap.read()
  sys.stderr.write('AFTER SUCCESS ' + f + '\n')
```

However, the standard error outputs in the following order:

```
AFTER SUCCESS
[mpeg ...] 
[mpeg ...]
...
BEFORE VIDCAP
```

It doesn't make sense how can it happen in this order, some broken videos should be seen somewhere between BEFORE and AFTER. (And the ones following or preceding are not broken neither if I try to open them individually.)

My last idea was to create for every video a file, making it as the stderr and check the non-empty files. (I know it's insanely inefficient, but I didn't have any other idea.)

```
for f in os.listdir(folder):
  sys.stderr = open(f + '.txt', 'w')
  vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(folder,f))
  success, image = vidcap.read()
```

This doesn't work also, all the error files are empty, although the messages still appear on standard error.

---

So my questions are the following:

1. What would be an efficient solution for this problem?
2. How is this order of outputs (first code example) possible? There is some parallelism under the hood?
3. Where are this messages going if not to the standard error (second code example)? If yes, why are they printed to the console instead of the specified error file?

Comment: OpenCV is the wrong tool for the job. use ffmpeg/ffprobe with `-of json` to analyze files (use `import subprocess`) or PyAV (`pip install pyav`).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Christoph Rackwitz, opencv is not the right tool here. You need to run ffmpeg on its own. `pyav` might give you a finer control but here is what I'd do with ffmpeg.

> 1. What would be an efficient solution for this problem?

Run ffmpeg (with `subprocess.run`) to decode your files to stdout with stdout mapped to a null pipe. Meanwhile, set stderr (text) pipe so you capture all the log messages. You can check the `returncode` of the `subprocess.run` output. If it is nonzero, that video has a critical error, which prevented reading the entire file. If it is zero, you can scan `stderr` str for the aforementioned error messages. You unfortunately need to know all the errors beforehand as there will be a lot of `[mpeg4 ...` lines.

That's about as efficient of a solution as I can think of.

> 2. How is this order of outputs (first code example) possible? There is some parallelism under the hood?

Depends on how `opencv` uses ffmpeg. It could be capturing all the ffmpeg log messages and only display them when you are done with the file.

> 3. Where are this messages going if not to the standard error (second code example)? If yes, why are they printed to the console instead of the specified error file?

This relates back to the above 2 answers. `opencv` is calling ffmpeg as a subprocess and it is likely capturing `stderr` of the ffmpeg subprocess.

If you'd rather not learn how to run `ffmpeg` you can try my `ffmpegio` library (`pip install ffmpegio-core` if you are using NumPy already you can also do `pip install ffmpegio`) and try this code:

```py
import ffmpegio
import os
out = ffmpegio.ffmpegprocess.run(
    {"inputs": [(filename, None)], 
     "outputs": [(os.devnull, {"f": "rawvideo"})]},
    overwrite=True,
    capture_log=True,
)
print(out.returncode)
print(out.stderr)
```

Be aware there will be a long pause till it finish reading the file. If you want to see the progress, you can use the `progress` option.

Post a comment if you need more specific help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i tried.

```
import av
from rich.progress import track

for vid in track(df.video_id):
    try:
        with av.open(vid) as container:
            stream = container.streams.video[0]
            average_fps = int(stream.average_rate)
    except:
        
        print(vid)
        os.remove(vid)
```